# return statement in a function to print all the lists after for loop

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to use python regular expressions to print desired items out of a text file which contains the strings like:

---

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jttoivon hyad-all    2356 Dec 11 11:50 add_colab_link.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  164519 Dec 28 17:59 basics.ipynb
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  164477 Nov  5 19:21 basics.ipynb.orig
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  115587 Dec 11 11:50 bayes.ipynb
```

---

For this I have written a function in the code below. The function only returns the list from the first row of the file. I want to get all the lists out of all the rows present in the file

```
import re
def file_listing(filename="src/listing.txt"):
    with open('listing.txt','r') as f:
        for i in range(47):
            line = f.readline()
            lists = re.findall(r'[-d]\w+\W+\w*\W+\w*\W*\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\W+\w+\s+(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\W+(\d+)\s+(\w*\W?\w*\W?\w*.\w+)', line)
            return lists
print(file_listing("listing.txt"))
```

This code gives:

```
[('2356', 'Dec', '11', '11', '50', 'add_colab_link.py')]
```

However, I want the function to iterate through all the rows in the file and return the lists of desired items for all the rows

Answer (score 0):

Returning from a function ends its processing, nothing is done afterwards.

```
 return lists
```

will therefor leave the function after the first line.

Fix:

```
import re

def file_listing(filename="src/listing.txt"):
    all_hits = []

    with open('listing.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if not line.strip():
                continue  # ignore empty lines
            all_hits.append( re.findall(r'[-d]\w+\W+\w*\W+\w*\W*\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\W+\w+\s+(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\W+(\d+)\s+(\w*\W?\w*\W?\w*.\w+)', line) )

    return all_hits 
print(file_listing("listing.txt"))
```

I did not verify your regex as it seems to find what you want.

Output:

```
[[('2356', 'Dec', '11', '11', '50', 'add_colab_link.py')], 
 [('164519', 'Dec', '28', '17', '59', 'basics.ipynb')], 
 [('164477', 'Nov', '5', '19', '21', 'basics.ipynb.orig')], 
 [('115587', 'Dec', '11', '11', '50', 'bayes.ipynb')]]
```

There might not ever be 2 matches per line - so you could use list.extend() instead.